# How to invoke lambda expression when calling sql query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda, entity-framework-6

I need to create a generic method (`ContainsLambda`) that takes collection and a lambda expression (a single property) and would check if the given property contains values in the given collection.

Here is my method

```
public static TModel[] ContainsLambda<TModel, TKey>(IEnumerable<TKey> keys, Func<TModel, TKey> property)
{
    DbSet<TModel> repository = DbContext.Set<TModel>();

    return repository.Where(x => keys.Contains(property.Invoke(x)))
                     .ToArray();
}
```

Then I would call it using something like this `ContainsLambda<Customer, int>(new List<int> {10, 20, 30}, p => p.Age)`

The above code throws the following runtime error.

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32
>   Invoke(Customer)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a
>   store expression.

How can I call `.Invoke()` on a lambda that would be used in LINQ which would then be translated into SQL expression?

Comment: Wouldn't it just be `property(x)`?

Comment: OP you need Expression<> but I don't know if EF will support a contains like that on its own

Comment: In any case, this is a known limitation of Linq to Entities.  The best way to solve it is usually to [write a custom query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql).  Otherwise, you'll have to pull all the entities over the wire first and use ordinary Linq.

Comment: @RobertHarvey that just gives me a different error `The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.`

Comment: Is there a way to create a special translation for the Invoke method to return the given property name?

Comment: What sort of code is in your Func?

Comment: Can you assume the cost of getting the entire DbSet from the database first, and then using your ContainsLambda function on the resulting in-memory collection using ordinary Linq?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making your repository an enumerable.  This bypasses Linq to Entities, and causes your code to run in Linq to Objects.

```
return repository.AsEnumerable()
                 .Where(x => keys.Contains(property.Invoke(x)))
                 .ToArray();
```

If you don't want all of the records in your repository to travel across the wire (i.e. you need the filtering to run on the server), you will have to [write a custom SQL query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) to retrieve the data.